# MVC2 Html.ValidationMessageFor: add htmlAttributes but keep the default message

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to change the htmlAttributes of the code rendered by my `Html.ValidationMessageFor`, but I want the message displayed to be the "default".

The overload options are:
A) `Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression)`
B) `Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression, validationMessage)`
C) `Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression, validationMessage, htmlAttributesObject)`

I wish there was a `Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression, htmlAttributesObject)` option, but there is not.

How can I achieve the desired result with option C? That is, where is that "default" messages stored? Is there an clean, easy way to get at it, so I can plug it in to the validationMessage parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you don't want to override the default message, simply supply an empty string and MVC will use the default message:

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.propertyName, string.Empty, new { attribs ... }) %>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I guess I assumed passing an empty string would render (or not, as it were) an empty string for the message. Is the fact that empty strings as parameters won't override a helper default some sort of ASP.NET or more general .NET convention? Or is that behavior variable on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: Neither really.  I found out about this functionality by looking at the source code,  Its worth looking when you get the chance.  Its been done this way because there couldn't be a separate method just taking the two parameters you were originaly wanting to use, without the method signature clashing with (expression, validationMessage).

Comment: how do I pass in the HTMLAttribute (3rd param) to tell it to show this validation on a new line or under the field it is validing?

Comment: Either include a line break (<br>) in your error message, or simply include the ValidationMessage in a separate lien within your page markup